# Rails 3 generator's git option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 2.x I could pass on a --git option to ./script/generate to add files to git automatically after creation. However I have been unable to find such an option (or configuration) in Rails 3.0.

Has this been removed or am I missing something? I tried researching this for a while but I am unable to find any reference.

Thanks,
Prateek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have an option like that, although the standard 'rails new' command does generate the .gitignore and .gitkeep files for you.

Otherwise, I think you need to set up the git project yourself.